# jQuery function not working to change the menu item color

Tags: jquery

HTML page is having an un-ordered list, we want that whenever clicked on any list items the back-ground color should be changed as below :
Suppose three Items in the list l1, l2, l3
When user click l1 the

element should change its background color, when l2 is clicked

belongs to l2 should be of changed color and making l1 to its normal color. Below is my code, may someone help me to identify what wrong I am doing and how to overcome it.

```js
     $('.nav').on('click', 'li', function(){
                    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                });
```

```css
                li.active {
                    background-color: red;
                    color: #000;
                    cursor: default;
                }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
             <title>Header</title>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

       </head>
       <body>
          <header>
            <div>
              <ul class="nav">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Tutorials</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Newsletter</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </header>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You need to wrap your code in the DOMReady event (i.e. `$(function() {  });`).

Comment: it's seems working for me already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to move your script after the HTML content (just before the body ends), or you need to wrap your JS code in DOMReady event, as @BenM mentioned in the comments.

---

You may refer to the following working examples:

**Using DOMReady event:**

```css
li.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: #000;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.nav').on('click', 'li', function() {
      $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
  });
</script>
<header>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Tutorials</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Newsletter</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

**By moving script at the end:**

```css
li.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: #000;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Tutorials</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Newsletter</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<script>
  $('.nav').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It might also be better to replace `$('.nav li').removeClass('active');` with `$(this).siblings().removeClass('active')`.

Comment: @BenM -- of course, but I wanted to just point out the actual problem with the code, instead of refactoring it for better. :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct format

as per DOM jquery

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
         <title>Header</title>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            li.active {
                background-color: red;
                color: #000;
                cursor: default;
            }
        </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Tutorials</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Newsletter</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </header>
      <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.nav').on('click', 'li', function(){
                $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
            });

        })
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```